# What is the different between "AMP non-rich results" and "AMP article" in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, amp

In my Google Search Console I found this in "Performance on Search results":

[image]

What is the difference between "AMP non-rich results" and "AMP article" here?  Both appear to be for the AMP articles we publish.

Comment: Have you found clear defination?

Answer (score 2):

AMP article means result with graphical data. It may include image or something else.

AMP non-rich result means simply text and link.

See attached images.

[image][image]